# Pandas dataframe finding the mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flask, mean

[image]

I have a dataframe that looks like the attached image. I want to find the mean for every finalAward_band 'value'. I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You need to load the dataframe in correct form. Finding mean for the given slice would be straightforward after that

Answer (score 0):

`str.contains`  can be used to perform either substring searches or regex based search. The search defaults to regex-based unless you explicitly disable it.

Sometimes regex search is not required, so specify regex=False to disable it.

```
#select all rows containing "finalAward_band"
df1[df1['col'].str.contains('finalAward_band', regex=False)]
# same as df1[df1['col'].str.contains('finalAward_band')] but faster.
```